# Merge Azure Blobs (PDFs) into one Blob and download to user via C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, pdf, blob

I have an ASP.NET Azure web application written in C# that involves the user uploading different pdfs into Azure Blob storage. I'd like the user to later download a combined PDF inclusive of previously-uploaded blobs in a specific order. Any idea on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have your broken this into smaller components and made an attempt? Download all relevant blobs, use a library to combine the PDF's, provide the resulting file to the user? What part are you having trouble with? Stack Overflow isn't just here to write code for you, so you should make an attempt. If you get stuck, provide a [mcve] and then you'll have a valid question.

Comment: @mason, thank you for your comment. I went with creating an Azure Function as outlined by SwethaKandikonda-MT and it was a success. I understand you were not pleased with my general inquiry, though it was on purpose in order to solicit a diverse response. Best regards.

Comment: It's irrelevant whether I'm pleased or not with your question. What's more important is that you understand the expectations of someone asking a question here. We're not here to outline how to do things. It's up to you to break your problem up, plan out the things you need to do, and try to implement them. If you get stuck with a specific part, you need to explain what you're doing and what's not working about your attempt. Every time. It's not about pleasing anybody - it's about satisfying the requirements of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 workarounds that you can try

1. Use of Azure Functions.
2. Download your pdf files from Azure Blob to your local computer, then merge them.

**Use of Azure Functions**

1. Create an azure function project and use the HTTP Trigger.
2. Make sure you install the below packages before getting started with coding.
3. Create the Function code.
4. Create Azure function in the portal.
5. Publish the code.

We are ready to start writing code. We need two files:

1. **ResultClass.cs**  – returns the merged file(s) as a list.
2. **Function1.cs**  – CCode that takes the file names from the URL, grabs them from the Storage account, merges them into one, and returns a download URL.

**ResultClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FunctionApp1
{

    public class Result
    {

        public Result(IList<string> newFiles)
        {
            this.files = newFiles;
        }

        public IList<string> files { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**Function1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {

        static Function1()
        {

            // This is required to avoid the "No data is available                         for encoding 1252" exception when saving the PdfDocument
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<Result> SplitUploadAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            //container where files will be stored and accessed for retrieval. in this case, it's called temp-pdf
            [Blob("temp-pdf", Connection = "")] CloudBlobContainer outputContainer,
            ILogger log)
        {
            //get query parameters

            string uriq = req.RequestUri.ToString(); 
            string keyw = uriq.Substring(uriq.IndexOf('=') + 1);

            //get file name in query parameters
            String fileNames = keyw.Split("mergepfd&filenam=")[1];

            //split file name
            string[] files = fileNames.Split(',');

            //process merge
            var newFiles = await this.MergeFileAsync(outputContainer, files);

            return new Result(newFiles);

        }

        private async Task<IList<string>> MergeFileAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, string[] blobfiles)
        {
            //init instance
            PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

            //loop through files sent in query
            foreach (string fileblob in blobfiles)
            {
                String intfile = $"" + fileblob;

                // get file
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(intfile);

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);

                    //get file content
                    string contents = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
                   
                    //open document
                    var inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(memoryStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

                    //get pages
                    int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
                    {
                        //append
                        outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[idx]);
                    }


                }
            }


            var outputFiles = new List<string>();
            var tempFile = String.Empty;

            //call save function to store output in container
            tempFile = await this.SaveToBlobStorageAsync(container, outputDocument);

            outputFiles.Add(tempFile);

            //return file(s) url
            return outputFiles;
        }

        private async Task<string> SaveToBlobStorageAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, PdfDocument document)
        {

            //file name structure
            var filename = $"merge-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")}-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4)}.pdf";

            // Creating an empty file pointer
            var outputBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //save result of merge
                document.Save(stream);
                await outputBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            }

            //get sas token
            var sasBlobToken = outputBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
            });

            //return sas token
            return outputBlob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
        }
    }
}
```

**Download your pdf files from Azure Blob to your local computer, then merge them**

```
 internal static void combineNormalPdfFiles()
        {
            String inputFilePath1 = @"C:\1.pdf";
            String inputFilePath2 = @"C:\2.pdf";
            String inputFilePath3 = @"C:\3.pdf";
            String outputFilePath = @"C:\Output.pdf";
            String[] inputFilePaths = new String[3] { inputFilePath1, inputFilePath2, inputFilePath3 };

            // Combine three PDF files and output.
            PDFDocument.CombineDocument(inputFilePaths, outputFilePath);
        }
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Azure Function to combine PDF Blobs in Azure Storage Account (Blob container)](https://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=c%23+merge+blobs+into+one+in+azure&d=4639986582814863&mkt=en-IN&setlang=en-US&w=k9bPtR-bTpo-BY6RLQV3IuRRq-6DdcpN)
2. [C# Merge PDF SDK: Merge, combine PDF files in C#.net, ASP.NET, MVC, Ajax, WinForms, WPF](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-merge/)

Comment: SwethaKandikonda-MT, this was an amazing solution and one that I have successfully incorporated into my website. My many sincere thanks to you for responding! I hadn't worked with Azure Functions prior to your comment, but I know so much more now. Ordering and compiling uploaded azure blob PDFs into one PDF was something I nearly gave up on until this.